# str.split error columns must be same length as key, multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe `df_ip_month` and am trying to split the column `detail EOBs` into multiple columns on the same row for each `Account` such that this

[image]

becomes this

[image]

The code I am trying to use is

```
df_ip_month[['eob1','eob2','eob3','eob4','eob5','eob6']] = df_ip_month['detail EOBs'].str.split(expand=True)
```

However, no output is generated, only the following error

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

How come?

Here is the dataset

```
df_ip_month = pd.DataFrame({'Account': ['H5000570011700','H5000484349900','H5000500029400','H5000502860000','H5000631774400','H5000619680500',
                           'H5000587425100','H5000630746300','H5000632095500','H5000505467800','H5000558994900','H5000623617700',
                           'H5000539983300','H5000559033600','H5000570061901','H5000513787300','H5000562451100','H5000568554900'], 
               'detail EOBs': ['','','','','','5002','','5002 1442','','5003','','','','5002 3035 9932 3343 3021 2312','','','5003 3035 9932','']})
```

Comment: In all cases but one, you have fewer than 6 values. They cannot be assigned to six columns. You may get a better answer if you provide the data as text, not as an image.

Comment: Please read: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). We cannot recreate your problem if it is in image format.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm pretty new to Stack. I included the data set per the pandas example for easier reproduction. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = df.set_index('Account')
df2 = df['detail_EOBs'].str.split(expand=True)
df.join(df2)
```

You can set your index on your `Account` column, split and expand your `detail_EOBs` column, then join them back together.